# My global variable isn't recognised within a function (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, function, variables, scope

My programming level is fairly elementary so a 'coding for idiots' type of explanation would be great...

I have the following code:

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'user';
$password = 'password';
$db_name = 'db_name';
$connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password);

mysqli_select_db($connect, $db_name) or die ("Couldn't connect"); 

function roll_die() {

    $throw = rand(1, 6);
    return $throw;
}

function get_subtotal() {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM throws";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['value']."<br>";
    }
}

?>
```

I get an error because the '$connect' in the function subtotal() is apparently undefined. How can that be if it's defined at the top of the page? Wouldn't that make it a global function?

Please don't just give me the correct code to fix this. Could you explain what's going on and how PHP defines and stores variables?

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn’t be relying on global functions. They’re difficult to keep track of as your codebase grows, and can be modified which can cause strange—and annoying—bugs in your application. Instead, inject variables into your classes and functions, i.e. `function get_subtotal($connection) {`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Martin. I'll start incorporating better practices.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer.

At the top of the page:

$connect = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);

Then within the function:

global $connect;

Actually, I found the answer in another question which was essentially asking the same thing, so apologies for the repost.

Comment: Might be worth deleting the question in that case.